# How to use a VBA variable for the lookup value in VLookup across multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to retrieve multiple datas from a source workbook to store in a target workbook using VBA. I have managed to do this for a single item of data using the statement:

```
Range("I5").Formula = "=VLookup(G5,'C:\TestFolder\[Test Source V1.0.xlsm]Tickets'!$A$9:$G$17, 4, False)"
```

in the immediate window or:

```
ws.Cells(Row, 9).Formula = "=VLookup(G5,'C:\TestFolder\[Test Source V1.0.xlsm]Tickets'!$A$9:$G$17, 4, False)"
```

in the procedure window.

However, my final aim is to retrieve several items of data by placing the above statement in a `Do Until loop` and replacing the `G5` lookup value with a variable which gets updated on every pass through the loop.

However, when I replace `G5` with a variable that scrolls through values ranging from `$G$1`, `$G$2`, `$G$3`, which point to the cells containing the actual lookup values(strings)  I get #Name? errors appearing in the destinations cells.

NB the destination cell range for the retrieved data is also incremented in the loop, see attached picture

[image]

The picture shows the target file, lookup values are in column G, Remote workbook name in column `H` and Column `I` holds the formulas created by the VBA code producing the `#NAME?` errors

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcavM.png)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you've not included quotes around the value you're placing in the formula

```vb
Dim S
s = "A1B2D4-222"

ws.Cells(Row, 9).Formula = _
  "=VLookup(""" & S & """,'C:\TestFolder\[Test Source V1.0.xlsm]Tickets'!$A$9:$G$17, 4, False)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim, I'm new to VBA and it's taking me a while to get my head around the syntax and methodology.  Your suggestion didn't work exactly but it certainly pointed me in the right direction and a minor tweak did the trick. With your suggestion the following statement put the LookUp Value (Cell Ref) in quotes and so it resulted in #N/A errors as below.
=VLOOKUP("$G$3",'[Test Source V1.0.xlsm]Tickets'!$A$9:$G$17, 4, FALSE)
[Results with errors][1]

However, removing two sets of double quotes either side of the ampersand, gave me what I needed i.e. just the cell reference as below.
ws.Cells(Row, 9).Formula = "=VLookup(" & LookVal & ",'C:\TestFolder[Test Source V1.0.xlsm]Tickets'!$A$9:$G$17, 4, False)"
[Correct formula and Results][2]

Many thanks for your help, much appreciated
I'm still not sure why the variable would need to be wrapped in ampersands and quotes but will do some further reading.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5aaW.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mshS.png